# Sound waveform visualisation question

Tags: visualization

Sorry about the wooly title, but I couldn't think of a concise way to describe this question.

I have a ZX Spectrum emulator project which can visualise the output from the sound chip [example here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hi-x5tFe5vY). I think it's an accurate depiction, but I'm outputting the waves just as they are generated in real time from left to right. This makes the waves jump around a lot in the visualisation. Whereas other visualisations I've seen and in oscilloscopes for example, the wave stay in place.

I guess I'd like to achieve an effect similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eslG9bg8jLA).

Could anyone point me at the terminology I need or any resources that I could look for for algorithms that would make the visualisation more stable?

Thanks in advance,

Steve.

Comment: what you're looking for in terms of oscilloscope functionality is called *trigger*; the kind of triggering you want isn't clear to me. It's probably best if you actually played with an actual oscilloscope to figure out what you want.

Comment: You only get a stable picture on an oscilloscope if your signal is reasonably  periodic.  That's not really the case for your sound waveforms.

Comment: Thanks both. I've edited the question for clarity... added a link to the effect I'm trying for.

Comment: Then you'll need some sort of a trigger.